# What is the proper way to reference a static variable on a Swift Protocol?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

Assume a protocol defined below:

```
protocol Identifiable {
  static var identifier: String { get }
}
extension Identifiable {
  static var identifier: String { return "Default Id" }
}
```

What is the best way to reference the static variable? The example below illustrates two ways to access the variable. What is the difference, and is the `type(of:)` better?

```
func work<I: Identifiable>(on identifiable: I) {
  let identifier: String = I.identifier
  print("from Protocol: \(identifier)")

  let identiferFromType: String = type(of: identifiable).identifier
  print("using type(of:): \(identiferFromType)")
}

struct Thing: Identifiable {
  static var identifier: String { return "Thing" }
}

work(on: Thing())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you show, there is no difference. Because `identifier` is a protocol *requirement*, it will be dynamically dispatched to in both cases, therefore you don't need to worry about the wrong implementation being called.

However, one difference arises when you consider the value of `self` inside the `static` computed property when classes conform to your protocol.

`self` in a static method/computed property is the metatype value that it's is called on. Therefore when called on `I`, `self` will be `I.self` – which is the *static* type that the compiler infers the generic placeholder `I` to be. When called on `type(of: identifiable)`, `self` will be the *dynamic* metatype value for the `identifiable` instance.

In order to illustrate this difference, consider the following example:

```
protocol Identifiable {
    static var identifier: String { get }
}

extension Identifiable {
    static var identifier: String { return "\(self)" }
}

func work<I : Identifiable>(on identifiable: I) {
    let identifier = I.identifier
    print("from Protocol: \(identifier)")

    let identiferFromType = type(of: identifiable).identifier
    print("using type(of:): \(identiferFromType)")
}

class C : Identifiable {}
class D : C {}

let d: C = D()

// 'I' inferred to be 'C', 'type(of: d)' is 'D.self'.
work(on: d)

// from Protocol: C
// using type(of:): D
```

In this case, "which is better" completely depends on the behaviour you want – static or dynamic.

Comment: possible to get a dynamic type of self in the static var?

Comment: @seanwoodward `self` in the static var is a metatype value – the dynamic type of such a value would be the a type of a type, which isn't particularly useful.

Comment: Say you have a computed property implemented in the extension on `Identifiable` and in `D`, but not `C`. Is it possible in this example to get the computed property from the implementation in `D` in `work(on:)` without specific casting?

Comment: Using `unsafeBitCast(identifiable, to: type(of: identifiable))` only returns the computed property from the protocol extension. I think it should return from the class implementation.

Comment: @seanwoodward I don't believe that's possible without casting if that computed property isn't a protocol requirement, as it'll be statically dispatched to. Inside `work(to:)`, the only implementation that could be statically dispatched to is the one in the extension.