# Is there any way to store a static property on a Protocol definition in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Say I have a protocol

```
protocol MyProtocol {
   /// A bunch of useful static properties
}

extension MyProtocol {
    static var allImplementors: [any MyProtocol.Type] {
        [MyProtocolImplementorA.self, MyProtocolImplementorB.self]
    }
}
```

Which to me seems all well. When I go to use it I have:

```
@State var currentSelected: any MyProtocol.Type = MyProtocolImplementorA.self
```

But when I try to use:

```
@State var currentSelected: any MyProtocol.Type = .allImplementors.first!
```

It fails with Type 'any MyProtocol.Type' has no member 'allImplementors' even though the autocomplete works.

How should I be doing this? or should I just create a helper class with the static:

```
class MyProtocolStatic {
   static let allImplementors: [any MyProtocol.Type] = [MyProtocolImplementorA.self, MyProtocolImplementorB.self]
}
```

Comment: Check these: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35043292/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/42495138/1187415

Comment: Have you tried declaring to declare de variable and then implementing in an extension like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955749/what-is-the-proper-way-to-reference-a-static-variable-on-a-swift-protocol ??

Answer (score 1):

From: [Swift: Providing a default protocol implementation in a protocol extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043292/swift-providing-a-default-protocol-implementation-in-a-protocol-extension)

Seems like the answer is no. I'm just going to use a helper class.